# Oracle Stored Procedure execution plan in case of IF ELSE

Tags: oracle, performance, stored-procedures, jdbc

I have a question, how is the execution plan of a stored procedure created if it has a IF ELSE statement wherein based on the value of a IN parameter IF or ELSE block is executed and the queries in the blocks are fetching same values from same tables but with a different column in where clause.

As far as I know there will be only one execution plan per stored procedure. If a Java application is calling the stored procedure using plain JDBC, the execution plan gets created first time the procedure is called and the block(IF) gets executed is used for creating the execution plan.

Next time when ELSE block is executed it uses the same execution plan and hence the execution will be slow.

I am asking this question because I am calling similar Stored procedure and time of execution is very different based on what value I am passing and which block is executed.

If this is the case what can be done to improve the performance. Should a seperate procedure be written instead of using IF ELSE.

PFB the stored procedure code:

```
PACKAGE         COP00134_006_1 AS
    TYPE t_cur_type IS REF CURSOR;
    PROCEDURE GetConsignmentDetails(
      sPInputList     IN VARCHAR2,
      sPInputType     IN VARCHAR2,
      cPCon           OUT t_cur_type,
      cPStatus        OUT t_cur_type,
      sPError         OUT VARCHAR2);
END COP00134_006_1;
```

Implementation:

```
PACKAGE BODY         COP00134_006_1 AS
    PROCEDURE GetConsignmentDetails(
      sPInputList     IN VARCHAR2,
      sPInputType     IN VARCHAR2,
      cPCon           OUT t_cur_type,
      cPStatus        OUT t_cur_type,
      sPError         OUT VARCHAR2)
    IS
    BEGIN
        sPError := '0';
        IF sPInputType = 'CON' THEN
         OPEN cPCon FOR
           SELECT 
                    con_id
                   ,con_legacy_id
                   ,con_create_td
                   ,con_pickup_lt
                   ,con_deliv_due_lt
                   ,CON_DELIV_END_LT
                   ,SRP_ID_AREA_DEST
                   ,CON_CLNT_REF_TX
                   ,BUL_CSYS_ID_ORIG
                   ,BUL_ID_ORIG
                   ,BUL_NM_ORIG
                   ,BUL_NM_DEST
                   ,cpn_oa_town_nm_r
                   ,cpn_oa_town_nm_d
                   ,cou_iso_id_orig
                   ,Cou_Nm_Orig
                   ,cou_iso_id_dest
                   ,Cou_Nm_Dest
                   ,PCE_QT
                   ,DUPLICATES
                   ,COS_SIGN_NM FROM (
             SELECT  /*+ cardinality (b 3) */ 
                    co.con_id
                   ,co.con_legacy_id
                   ,co.con_create_td
                   ,co.con_pickup_lt
                   ,co.con_deliv_due_lt
                   ,co.CON_DELIV_END_LT
                   ,co.SRP_ID_AREA_DEST
                   ,co.CON_CLNT_REF_TX
                   ,co.BUL_CSYS_ID_ORIG
                   ,blOrig.BUL_ID as BUL_ID_ORIG
                   ,blOrig.BUL_NM as BUL_NM_ORIG
                   ,blDest.BUL_NM as BUL_NM_DEST
                   ,cnr.cpn_oa_town_nm as cpn_oa_town_nm_r
                   ,cnd.cpn_oa_town_nm as cpn_oa_town_nm_d
                   ,co.cou_iso_id_orig
                   ,cuOrig.Cou_nm as Cou_Nm_Orig
                   ,co.cou_iso_id_dest
                   ,cuDest.Cou_nm as Cou_Nm_Dest
                   ,(select count(*) from CORPCV01 PC WHERE PC.CON_ID = CO.CON_ID) PCE_QT
                   ,CASE WHEN COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY CON_LEGACY_ID) > 1 THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END AS DUPLICATES
                   ,cs.COS_SIGN_NM, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CS.CON_ID ORDER BY COS_EVENT_TD) SEQ_NR
               FROM corcov01 co
              INNER JOIN corcnv01 cnr
                 ON cnr.con_id = co.con_id
                AND cnr.cpn_type_cd = 'R'
               LEFT OUTER JOIN corcnv01 cnd
                 ON cnd.con_id = co.con_id
                AND cnd.cpn_type_cd = 'D'
              INNER JOIN ncrcuv01 cuOrig
                 ON cuOrig.COU_ISO_ID = co.COU_ISO_ID_ORIG
                AND TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE) BETWEEN cuOrig.COU_EFFECT_DT AND cuOrig.COU_EFFECT_TO_DT
              INNER JOIN ncrcuv01 cuDest
                 ON cuDest.COU_ISO_ID = co.COU_ISO_ID_DEST
                AND TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE) BETWEEN cuDest.COU_EFFECT_DT AND cuDest.COU_EFFECT_TO_DT
              LEFT OUTER JOIN ncrblv01 blOrig
                 ON blOrig.BUL_CSYS_ID = co.BUL_CSYS_ID_ORIG
                AND TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE) BETWEEN blOrig.BUL_EFFECT_DT AND blOrig.BUL_EFFECT_TO_DT
              LEFT OUTER JOIN ncrblv01 blDest
                 ON blDest.BUL_CSYS_ID = co.BUL_CSYS_ID_DEST
                AND TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE) BETWEEN blDest.BUL_EFFECT_DT AND blDest.BUL_EFFECT_TO_DT
              LEFT OUTER JOIN corcsv01 cs
                 ON co.con_id = cs.con_id 
                AND cs.cos_sign_nm is not null
                and cs.cos_delete_in = 'N'
               WHERE co.con_Legacy_Id IN ( select dataItem from TABLE(ZYADMIN.ZYP90008.GetListFromCSV(sPInputList)) b )
               )WHERE SEQ_NR = 1;
          OPEN cPStatus FOR
              SELECT csv.CON_ID AS CON_ID_COS
                    ,csv.XSF_ID
                    ,csv.XSS_ID
                    ,csv.XSG_ID
                    ,csv.XSD_ID
                    ,ndv.XSX_ID
                    ,ndv.xsd_customer_ds
                    ,BUL_CSYS_ID_OCC
                    ,nlv.BUL_NM as BUL_NM_OCC
                    ,csv.COS_EVENT_LT
                    ,ndv.XSD_SEVERITY_CD
                    ,qb.QLA_DS
                FROM corcsv01 csv 
               INNER JOIN corcov01 co
                  ON csv.con_id = co.con_id
               INNER JOIN ncrsdv01 ndv 
                  ON ndv.XSF_ID=csv.XSF_ID 
                 AND ndv.XSS_ID=csv.XSS_ID 
                 AND ndv.XSG_ID=csv.XSG_ID 
                 AND ndv.XSD_ID=csv.XSD_ID 
                 AND TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE) BETWEEN ndv.XSD_EFFECT_DT AND ndv.XSD_EFFECT_TO_DT 
               INNER JOIN ncrksv01 ks 
                  ON ndv.XSX_ID= ks.XSX_ID 
                 AND TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE) BETWEEN ks.SKT_EFFECT_DT AND ks.SKT_EFFECT_TO_DT 
                 AND ks.SCA_ID = 'WEB'
               LEFT OUTER JOIN ncrqav01 qa
                 ON qa.XSX_ID = ndv.XSX_ID
                AND qa.APP_ID = 'EXCO'
                AND TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE) BETWEEN QAS_EFFECT_DT AND QAS_EFFECT_TO_DT
               LEFT OUTER JOIN ncrqbv01 qb
                 ON qa.QLA_ID = qb.QLA_ID
                AND qa.APP_ID = qb.APP_ID
                AND TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE) BETWEEN QLA_EFFECT_DT AND QLA_EFFECT_TO_DT
               INNER JOIN ncrblv01 nlv 
                  ON nlv.BUL_CSYS_ID=csv.BUL_CSYS_ID_OCC 
                 AND TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE)BETWEEN nlv.BUL_EFFECT_DT AND nlv.BUL_EFFECT_TO_DT 
               WHERE co.con_Legacy_Id IN ( select dataItem from TABLE(ZYADMIN.ZYP90008.GetListFromCSV(sPInputList)) b );
        ELSE
         OPEN cPCon FOR
                    SELECT 
                    con_id
                   ,con_legacy_id
                   ,con_create_td
                   ,con_pickup_lt
                   ,con_deliv_due_lt
                   ,CON_DELIV_END_LT
                   ,SRP_ID_AREA_DEST
                   ,CON_CLNT_REF_TX
                   ,BUL_CSYS_ID_ORIG
                   ,BUL_ID_ORIG
                   ,BUL_NM_ORIG
                   ,BUL_NM_DEST
                   ,cpn_oa_town_nm_r
                   ,cpn_oa_town_nm_d
                   ,cou_iso_id_orig
                   ,Cou_Nm_Orig
                   ,cou_iso_id_dest
                   ,Cou_Nm_Dest
                   ,PCE_QT
                   ,DUPLICATES
                   ,COS_SIGN_NM FROM (
             SELECT  /*+ cardinality (b 3) */ 
                    co.con_id
                   ,co.con_legacy_id
                   ,co.con_create_td
                   ,co.con_pickup_lt
                   ,co.con_deliv_due_lt
                   ,co.CON_DELIV_END_LT
                   ,co.SRP_ID_AREA_DEST
                   ,co.CON_CLNT_REF_TX
                   ,co.BUL_CSYS_ID_ORIG
                   ,blOrig.BUL_ID as BUL_ID_ORIG
                   ,blOrig.BUL_NM as BUL_NM_ORIG
                   ,blDest.BUL_NM as BUL_NM_DEST
                   ,cnr.cpn_oa_town_nm as cpn_oa_town_nm_r
                   ,cnd.cpn_oa_town_nm as cpn_oa_town_nm_d
                   ,co.cou_iso_id_orig
                   ,cuOrig.Cou_nm as Cou_Nm_Orig
                   ,co.cou_iso_id_dest
                   ,cuDest.Cou_nm as Cou_Nm_Dest
                   ,(select count(*) from CORPCV01 PC WHERE PC.CON_ID = CO.CON_ID) PCE_QT
                   ,'FALSE' AS DUPLICATES
                   ,cs.COS_SIGN_NM, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CS.CON_ID ORDER BY COS_EVENT_TD) SEQ_NR
               FROM corcov01 co
              INNER JOIN corcnv01 cnr
                 ON cnr.con_id = co.con_id
                AND cnr.cpn_type_cd = 'R'
               LEFT OUTER JOIN corcnv01 cnd
                 ON cnd.con_id = co.con_id
                AND cnd.cpn_type_cd = 'D'
              INNER JOIN ncrcuv01 cuOrig
                 ON cuOrig.COU_ISO_ID = co.COU_ISO_ID_ORIG
                AND TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE) BETWEEN cuOrig.COU_EFFECT_DT AND cuOrig.COU_EFFECT_TO_DT
              INNER JOIN ncrcuv01 cuDest
                 ON cuDest.COU_ISO_ID = co.COU_ISO_ID_DEST
                AND TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE) BETWEEN cuDest.COU_EFFECT_DT AND cuDest.COU_EFFECT_TO_DT
              LEFT OUTER JOIN ncrblv01 blOrig
                 ON blOrig.BUL_CSYS_ID = co.BUL_CSYS_ID_ORIG
                AND TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE) BETWEEN blOrig.BUL_EFFECT_DT AND blOrig.BUL_EFFECT_TO_DT
              LEFT OUTER JOIN ncrblv01 blDest
                 ON blDest.BUL_CSYS_ID = co.BUL_CSYS_ID_DEST
                AND TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE) BETWEEN blDest.BUL_EFFECT_DT AND blDest.BUL_EFFECT_TO_DT
              LEFT OUTER JOIN corcsv01 cs
                 ON co.con_id = cs.con_id 
                AND cs.cos_sign_nm is not null
                and cs.cos_delete_in = 'N'
               WHERE co.CON_CLNT_REF_CR IN ( select dataItem from TABLE(ZYADMIN.ZYP90008.GetListFromCSV(sPInputList)) b )
               )WHERE SEQ_NR = 1;
          OPEN cPStatus FOR
              SELECT csv.CON_ID AS CON_ID_COS
                    ,csv.XSF_ID
                    ,csv.XSS_ID
                    ,csv.XSG_ID
                    ,csv.XSD_ID
                    ,ndv.XSX_ID
                    ,ndv.xsd_customer_ds
                    ,BUL_CSYS_ID_OCC
                    ,nlv.BUL_NM as BUL_NM_OCC
                    ,csv.COS_EVENT_LT
                    ,ndv.XSD_SEVERITY_CD
                    ,qb.QLA_DS
                FROM corcsv01 csv 
               INNER JOIN corcov01 co
                  ON csv.con_id = co.con_id
               INNER JOIN ncrsdv01 ndv 
                  ON ndv.XSF_ID=csv.XSF_ID 
                 AND ndv.XSS_ID=csv.XSS_ID 
                 AND ndv.XSG_ID=csv.XSG_ID 
                 AND ndv.XSD_ID=csv.XSD_ID 
                 AND TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE) BETWEEN ndv.XSD_EFFECT_DT AND ndv.XSD_EFFECT_TO_DT 
               INNER JOIN ncrksv01 ks 
                  ON ndv.XSX_ID= ks.XSX_ID 
                 AND TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE) BETWEEN ks.SKT_EFFECT_DT AND ks.SKT_EFFECT_TO_DT 
                 AND ks.SCA_ID = 'WEB'
               LEFT OUTER JOIN ncrqav01 qa
                 ON qa.XSX_ID = ndv.XSX_ID
                AND qa.APP_ID = 'EXCO'
                AND TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE) BETWEEN QAS_EFFECT_DT AND QAS_EFFECT_TO_DT
               LEFT OUTER JOIN ncrqbv01 qb
                 ON qa.QLA_ID = qb.QLA_ID
                AND qa.APP_ID = qb.APP_ID
                AND TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE) BETWEEN QLA_EFFECT_DT AND QLA_EFFECT_TO_DT
               INNER JOIN ncrblv01 nlv 
                  ON nlv.BUL_CSYS_ID=csv.BUL_CSYS_ID_OCC 
                 AND TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE)BETWEEN nlv.BUL_EFFECT_DT AND nlv.BUL_EFFECT_TO_DT 
               WHERE co.CON_CLNT_REF_CR IN ( select dataItem from TABLE(ZYADMIN.ZYP90008.GetListFromCSV(sPInputList)) b );
        END IF;
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
          sPError := '1' ||' '||SQLCODE||' '||SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 200);
    END;
END COP00134_006_1;
```

Issue is with the queries executed in ELSE part.
As mentioned in comments, I have run the same queries seperately and they are executed in less than a second while when same data is passed to procedure it takes more than a minute. I cannot run profiler as I don't have database access and the process of asking DBA for the same will take more than a week and I need to fix this as soon as possible

Comment: AFAI, yes you should if you have performance issues on retrieving data from DB via jdbc.

Comment: SQL queries have execution plans, not stored procedures (or any PL/SQL block of code for that matter).  So the execution plan will be considered per query within your stored procedure. You will not experience the problem the way you describe it.

Comment: @cihanseven - not sure what you mean. JDBC is capable of fine performance, provided it's been properly configured.

Comment: @APC i'm not mentioning that the performance issue is about JDBC. It works fine, no problem. I intend on taking attention on the waste of time on stored procedures. But misunderstood i guess, no problem bro :)

Answer (score 0):

Oracle builds execution plans for queries not stored procedures. So each query in your stored procedure will have its own execution plan. You say this about yoour queries:

> "with a different column in where clause"

Different columns means different access paths: this might translate into different use of indexes, different disk read activity, potentially different volumes of data. So it wouldn't be surprising to experience different performance depending on which branch of the IF...ELSE is taken. Having separate procedures wouldn't change the performance of the underlying queries.

To examine the differences, run EXPLAIN PLAN for each individual query. [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGSQL/tgsql_genplan.htm#TGSQL-GUID-E4ED3145-8ABD-4F40-B044-9AEFBD89409C). You'll need to cut'n'paste the statements into a SQL worksheet (or whatever tool you use for working with SQL).

---

If you think the problem lies in the stored procedure than you should investigate where the time goes with the PL/SQL profiler. [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADFNS/adfns_profiler.htm#ADFNS023). If it isn't installed already you'll probably need a DBA to install it.

---

> "when same queries are executed inside stored procedure with same values and on same data it is taking 60+ seconds"

You keep talking about elapsed times. How are you measuring these? What are you measuring? Where does the time go? This wouldn't be the first time the database got blamed for poor performance when the actual culprit was a bad network connection of a shonky JDBC configuration.

Comment: I have run explain plan for individual queries and the explain plan looks fine. Also the queries are getting executed in less than 0.5 secs. But when same queries are executed inside stored procedure with same values and on same data it is taking 60+ seconds.

Comment: We have reached the limits of what it is possible for folks on StackOverflow to do with the information you have provided so far. Diagnosis requires clues: it requires looking at the code, the raw data, sample inputs and outputs, explain plans and profiles.

Comment: I have added the stored procedure code. Hope I can get something.